# As someone studying philosophy and applying it to my life with success, how far does one take the ideals learnt?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, mind-body, stoicism, virtue-ethics

I am studying several philosophers and applying all the knowledge I am learning into a 'melting pot' of ideals and characteristics I am applying to my life to better myself and attempt to live more virtuously and less by impulses my ego generates.

But how far does one take this to be satisfied they are remaining virtuous?

For instance, I am currently bettering my diet, and I am considering whether I should cut out all sugar as sugar is something I've always been drawn to due to ego-related impulse. Is moderation appropriate or does that defeat the purpose; giving into my ego at any point willingly seems to go against the idea of living as virtuously as possible.

Another query I am battling with is lust, is masturbation acceptable in living a life of virtue? It was something that I did alot before making these lifestyle changes (I am 22) but it feels wrong to use pornography as that plays into impulse and lust just as I described having sugar in my diet is still giving into my ego.

Would one find it acceptable to use their imagination as a means to arousal or is that still lust gaining control, and I know from a medical standpoint regular masturbation has been shown to help with avoiding several medical problems down the line but it still feels like it goes against the ideals and virtues I am seeking to live and abide by.

This question stems to almost anything related to 'temporarily giving into ego' in some manner; whether it be getting angry someone cut me off, getting blinded by joy that I dont make logical decisions and remain in control of my thoughts and actions etc.

What are your thoughts on this, and suggestions (If you have reading material related to this please link it as well I would love to delve into the minds of geniuses of philosophy to get another perspective and understanding)

Comment: "What are your thoughts" questions and life advice questions are both off-topic on this site. We are taking academically minded questions that can be answered based on existing philosophical literature, and we have one question per post policy.

Comment: I understand, but I was proposing this question as a question in general, not only something applying to my individual life, but posing the question in such a matter to make it more practical and direct; my apologies I will ensure not to make this mistake again

Comment: You should apply what you learn to your life but first you would have to learn it. Just reading about a few speculative philosophical ideas is not learning how to live. You would need to go in search of reliable knowledge. I feel you're on the right track with your comment about the ego, Maybe checking out the kind of philosophy that deals with the ego and its clever games would be a way forward.

Comment: There is no consensus on what is the best way to live, even in philosophy.  Thus I’m afraid the answers you’re looking for are not to be found in books, but in the trial and error of life.

Comment: If you try to control your lust and eating at the same time, you may be headed for a weekend of complete debauchery and dissapation. :)  Try to achieve the happy medium instead. The middle road. Balance.

Comment: "Epicureanism argued that pleasure was the chief good in life.[18] Hence, Epicurus advocated living in such a way as to derive the greatest amount of pleasure possible during one's lifetime, yet doing so moderately in order to avoid the suffering incurred by overindulgence in such pleasure.[18]" Wikipedia I don't know if this is on your reading list. You may want to investigate it.

Comment: Thank you Kenshin I like that insight, and its very true for me; Learning through mistakes and the everyday struggles that life gives you has been allowing me to make great personal progress in my own journey. @Gordon I like that insight, living in a moderation where I can maintain my own personal idea of virtue but not miss out on life and the things it offers me; Always love getting new material to study and learn from thank you both for your insight and input!